# PHP и Python, неверная кодировка?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, unicode

Моей задачей было написать скрипт, который из PHP передавал бы переменную в Python скрипт, там переменная возвращалась, и PHP выводил переменную. Но проблема возникла при возврате значение переменной(русский текст).
Код PHP:

```
$hello = 'Виктор';
$result = shell_exec('main.py ' . $hello);
echo $result;
```

Код Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

text = sys.argv[1]
print (text)
```

Оба файла в utf-8 без BOM. Пробовал и .htaccess - не помогло. Результат: ������.

Как это можно исправить? У меня Windows 7, Python 3.5, редактор Notepad++.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том что, кодировка командной строки в windows не utf-8 и тут ничего не поделать, кроме как конвертировать кодировку как это в питоне я точно не скажу, ищите по iconv.

Кодировку можно узнать введя в консоли `chcp` и в русской версии обычно это 866

в питоне должно быть sys.argv[1].decode('866') как то так, ну и если вы это будете запускать где и в другом место то нужна будет проверка на ОС и кодировку

Comment: В Питоне 3 `sys.argv[1]` уже является Юникодной строкой, поэтому `.decode()` в корне неправильно здесь использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Код на Питоне в вопросе не имеет ни одного не ASCII символа в исходном коде, поэтому `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` декларация здесь совершенно бесполезна (не говоря о том, что utf-8 и так является кодировкой по умолчанию для исходного кода в Питоне 3) -- она не оказывает никакого влияния на то как `sys.argv[1]` содержимое получено или какая кодировка используется при печати `print(text)`.

Python 3 использует Юникодное API для получения аргументов с командной строки на Windows, поэтому `sys.argv[1]` содержимое должно быть верным, если php код правильный -- можно проверить напечатав строковое представление: `print(ascii(sys.argv[1]))` (должно получиться: `'\u0412\u0438\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440'`).

Кодировкой, используемой для `print(text)`, если необходимо, можно управлять с помощью `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменной окружения. Текущую кодировку можно посмотреть: `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`. Чтобы изолировать вопрос `sys.argv[1]` от `print(text)` можно начать с
`print('\u0412\u0438\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440')` и установить `PYTHONIOENCODING` в значение, которое php ожидает.

Чтобы обойти возможные баги с перекодировкой ввода/вывода на различных платформах и реализациях языков, можно использовать JSON формат, где все не-ASCII символы заэкранированы (выглядит как строковое представление Питона, но это не одно и то же):

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps({'text': 'Виктор'}))                
{"text": "\u0412\u0438\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440"} # так print(sys.argv[1]) выглядит
>>> json.loads(_)
{'text': 'Виктор'} # строковое представление словаря в Питоне
```

В php, можно `json_encode()`, `json_decode()` использовать (`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` флаг не использовать).

JSON также позволяет произвольные Юникодные символы использовать, а не только те, которые поддерживаются кодировкой, используемой в текущем окружении. Например, можно без проблем обмениваться эмотиконами такими как   [(U+1F44D THUMBS UP SIGN)](https://codepoints.net/U+1F44D).

Нужно понимать, что в разных контекстах могут использоваться разные кодировки: кодировка исходного кода не обязана совпадать с кодировкой, используемой для параметров, передаваемых с командной строки, которая не обязана совпадать с кодировкой стандартного ввода/вывода, которая может отличаться от кодировки html-странички, ожидаемой браузером и notepad может использовать кодировку отличную от кодировки, используемой в Windows консоле и т.д.

Стандартное решение -- использовать Юникод при работе с текстом -- то есть при вводе как можно скорее преобразовать входные байты в Юникодный текст, затем передавать внутри программы везде исключительно Юникодные строки (для представления текстовых данных) и преобразовывать Юникод назад в байты, только если это необходимо при общении с внешним миром -- это так называемая идея "Юникодного сэндвича".

Таким образом, только на границе программы с внешним миром приходится с кодировками иметь дело, а внутри только Юникод используется и поэтому избегаются ошибки, связанные с неверной интерпретацией текстовых данных разными частями программы.