# lower() меняет кодировку текста

Tags: php, кодировка, python-3.5

пытаюсь связать python с php, а именно - внедрить нейронные сети в сайт.
вызываю из php скрипт таким образом:

```
$x = shell_exec("python C:/Users/mx/script.py \"".$_POST["text"]."\" 2>&1");
echo($x);
```

в script.py написано следующее:

```
import sys
tx = sys.argv[1]
tx = tx.lower()
print(tx)
```

в итоге я вижу текст вида �����, но если я уберу строку `tx = tx.lower()`, то текст вернётся в нужной кодировке, так как я его вписал на странице. любые русские буквы превращаются в знаки вопроса, остальные символы отображаются нормально. 
при этом непосредственно из `cmd` всё работает как надо.

можно, конечно, подготовить текст в php, но, думаю, это не совсем правильно.

как получить текст в нормальной кодировке после обработки в python?

и ещё вопрос по поводу сброса вывода, мне в php нужна лишь последняя строка, т.е. непосредственно результат работы сети. я обложился функциями сброса:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
print(tx, flush=True)
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.exit()
```

однако всё равно возвращается лишняя строка: `Using TensorFlow backend.` , причём после вывода `print()`. как правильно получать от скрипта только нужные данные?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону похожей проблемы...

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141035/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ae%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5/359348#359348

Comment: что у вас `python -V` печатает в php окружении? (вы уверены, что именно 3.5?)

Comment: здесь множество движущихся частей, чтобы упростить: замените `$_POST["text"]` на фиксированную строку к примеру: `"\u{430}\u{431}\u{432}"`. В Питоне добавьте: `print(ascii(sys.argv[1]))` и `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`

Comment: про `flush=True` отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задайте.

Comment: через php `python --version` отвечает `Python 3.5.3`. 

`print(ascii(sys.argv[1]))` печатает `\\u{430}\\u{431}\\u{432}`.

`print(sys.stdout.encoding)` печатает `cp1251`.

одинаково и через консоль, и через php.

Comment: ещё заметил что когда `tx="текст"`, `len(tx)` выдаёт разные результаты: когда выполняю через php - показывает длину строки 10, когда через консоль - показывает 5. при этом кодировку они показали одинаковую, как так получилось?

Comment: Питон не должен видеть `\u` буквально. Что у вас: `echo "\u{430}\u{431}\u{432}" . phpversion();` показывает?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [PHP и Python, неверная кодировка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456399/23044)

Answer (score 0):

разобрался.

cmd работает в `cp1251`, php в `UTF-8`.

что бы нормально работало надо перед запуском `shell_exec` перекодировать текст в `cp1251`, иначе они будут иметь разную длину (при тестах из php и cmd текст выводился одинаково, однако len(text) показывал 10 для php, и 5 для cmd).

так же, для вывода нам надо перекодировать всё обратно, иначе мы будем видеть те самые �����.

```
$tx = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251", $_POST["text"]);
$cmd = "python C:/Users/mx/script.py \"".$tx."\" 2>&1";
$x = shell_exec($cmd);
$x = iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", $x);
echo($x);
```

помните что `shell_exec` потенциально опасная функция, всегда проверяйте то, что вы ей передаёте

Comment: Это может указывать, что shell_exec() использует ANSI (non-unicode) API на Windows, чтобы запустить команду. ANSI codepage может отличаться от cp1251 (к примеру, cp1252). Использование неверной кодировки может к кракозябрам вести. Это не имеет отношения к кодировке cmd (chcp, OEM codepage, к примеру cp866). Второе преобразование можно убрать, если [выставить PYTHONIOENCODING переменную окружения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453992/23044) (чтобы можно было принять от python команды вывод, которые не представим в ANSI cp, к примеру, `python -c "print(u'\N{SNOWMAN}')"`)